# How to filter the file using another file's value in python

Tags: python, file, filter, bioinformatics

So I have a file named sequence.txt and I've already split the file into lists and it looks like this:

The original file:

> 102L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
>
> 103L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
>
> 104L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSAAELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL

After I split them into lists:

```
['>102L', 'Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL']

['>103L', 'Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL']

['>104L', 'Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSAAELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL']
```

And I have another file named title.txt which contains all the name/title of the sequence that I want and it looks like this:

```
>102L
>104L
```

So I based on this title.txt file, I want to filter out all the sequence which title isn't in the title list, and store them into another file named filter_sequence.txt. So the results for the new file should look like this:

> 102L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
>
> 104L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSAAELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL

Noticed that There is no 103L anymore. I'm using python and I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

This is my final code:

```
import string

fin = open('title.txt')
all_titles = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
all_titles = map(string.strip, all_titles)

f = open('filtered_sequence.txt', 'w')
sequence_list = open('sequence.txt')
for sequence in sequence_list:
    lists = sequence.strip() # Strip the sequence file into lists of sequence
    if lists[0] in all_titles:
        write_string = lists[0] + lists[1] + "\n\n"
        f.write(write_string)

f.close()
```

The title.txt is:

```
>102L
>104L
```

The sequence.txt is:

```
102L     Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL

103L     Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNSLDAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL

104L     Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSAAELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
```

And I wish my filtered_sequence.txt looks like:

```
102L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
104L Sequence:MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSAAELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMLQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL
```

But the filtered_sequence.txt file is blank. Can you help me?

Comment: This code isn't going to get your `sequence.txt` file formatted the way you like. How were you doing it before? Can you show just that part of the code that you had?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense So I've just edited the code. That's the final code I'm using. And there is the file I'm using. But the generated filter_sequence.txt file is still blank. Can you help out?

Comment: Instead of `lists = sequence.strip()`, use `lists = sequence.split()`. Also, I see now that `sequence.txt` has titles `102L`, while `title.txt` has `>102L`. That extra `>` is going to mess up the code. You'll probably want to use a `for` loop to remove that `>` at the beginning of each title you import from `title.txt`. Lastly, you'll want to put a space between `lists[0]` and `lists[1]` when writing out.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense Sorry, the sequence.txt has titles >102L. For some reason it did showed up in the question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to store the second file in a list as well, I would imagine.

```
import string

f = open("title.txt","r")
all_titles = f.readlines()                # Get the data
f.close()
all_titles = map(string.strip,all_titles) # Strip off newlines.
```

Then `all_titles` contains `['>102L','>104L']`. From there, just do a "item in list" test:

```
f = open("filter_sequence.txt","w")       # The file to write to.

for sequence in sequence_list:
  if sequence[0] in all_titles:           # sequence[0] is the sequence title.
    write_string = str(sequence[0]) + ":\nSequence:" + str(sequence[1]) + "\n\n"
    f.write(write_string)                 # Write the string above.

f.close()                                 # Close the file.
```

That should do it well enough. `item in list` is a quick boolean test to see if any item in `list` is equal to `item`.

Note: if you want to write `102L` instead of `>102L`, you can strip off the first character of `sequence[0]` by writing `sequence[0][1:]` instead. That means to grab the substring starting with character 1 (which is the second character) and continue to the end.

Comment: Thanks! But there's some problem. When I run your code there's an error says:     all_title = map(string.strip, all_title)
NameError: name 'string' is not defined. I'm using python 2.7.8 FYI. And I have another question as well. How do you store the output in filter_sequence.txt?

Comment: Remember to use `import string` to grab the `string` module. I'll edit my answer for output.

Comment: Thanks again! But I'm not sure about sequence_list in your code, is it lists of sequences or just the sequence file? I have run your code and the new file I generated is blank. I have edit my question and it contains the file and code I'm using.

Comment: In this case, `sequence_list` would be the list of sequences; since sequences are also lists, it's basically a list of lists. I used it as a placeholder since I didn't know how you were storing these sequences internally. You can replace `for sequence in sequence_list` with however you want to refer to the sequences you read in from the first file.